# HTML href inside a button (like a chrome tab) 2 different click functions in 1 button

Tags: php, html

I want to have a X inside a button just like the X in the chrome tabs. So I have 4 buttons which will give me a POST when I click on 1 of them. Now I want to have a X icon inside that button to redirect to a different page/run a function

[Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyppc.png)

I tried to put a href inside the button but it doesn't work... the X will be blue like a href, but when i click on it, it will only click the button.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" style="background-color: #<?php echo $fontColor; ?>;width:240px;white-space:normal" type="submit" name="actief">
 <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
 <?php 
 echo $result['FIRST_NAME'], " ".$result['LAST_NAME'];
 echo $icon; 
 ?>                                              
</button>
```

Comment: @jameson2012 it is not the same. I edited my post with a better explaination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm understanding correctly, you want an element nested inside of the button to be clickable and fire a function only when this element is clicked. You also want a separate action to run if the button itself has been clicked.

You can run an event listener on the whole button then check if the element clicked via `e.target` was the button itself OR the X inside.

If i have misinterpreted your question please let me know and i will try and correct my answer.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const buttonClose = document.querySelector('.button__close');

button.addEventListener('click',(e)=> {
  if(e.target.classList == buttonClose.classList){
    alert('Close Clicked')
  }
});
```

```css
.button__close{
  background:white;
  padding:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<button>Example<span class='button__close'>x</span></button>
```

Comment: You understood correctly. I will try this tomorrow morning as soon as I get back to my pc. Thanks :)

Comment: It worked and it is great! Thank you. Do you know if it is possible to highlite the X when you move over it? Like the same when you move over the X at your internet tab.

Comment: Great! Yes you can simply add some CSS on hover to change the background colour. e.g. `.button__close:hover{background:purple;}`